# QLDB and Kotlin - "execute" method returning specific object

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, amazon-qldb

I am trying to execute an SQL statement at AWS QLDB like the example in the [AWS SDK Git](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-qldb-driver-java/blob/3e7f5a4f3498513fee9cd337b8a5f14c941bca9b/src/test/software/amazon/qldb/integrationtests/StatementExecutionIntegTest.java#L293) but using Kotlin. The example shows me that I can return something at "execute" (represented by "searchValue")

```
  String searchValue = driver.execute(
        txn -> {
            Result result = txn.execute(searchQuery);

            String value = "";
            for (IonValue row : result) {
                value = ((IonString) row).stringValue();
            }
            return value;
        });
```

Based on the example, I've tried to receive the return in "executionReturn" and transform the values at "let" function but "executionReturn" cames as undefined.

```
        val executionReturn = driver.execute { txn: TransactionExecutor ->
            val result: Result = txn.execute(
                "SELECT * FROM Table")
            )
            result

        }
        executionReturn.let {
            list.plus(it as IonStruct)
}
```

How could I return a specific value from "driver.execute"?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest in QLDB. Does something like the following help you?

```
        val executionReturn = driver.execute<List<IonValue>> { txn: TransactionExecutor ->
            val result = txn.execute(
                "SELECT * FROM Table").toList()
            result
        }
        executionReturn.let {
            list.plus(it as IonStruct)
        }
```

Comment: maybe should work, I've changed my approach

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the approach of the collection. I've created a mutableListOf and then used the method "add"

Then it worked